# bootstrap3 grid system - class dom vs css mixin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I hope someone has any idea what is the best solution

**class dom**

```
<div class="col-md-6">I'm on the left</div>
```

versus

**css mixin**

```
<div class="left">I'm on the left</div>
  /* --- with css --- */
  .left {
    .make-sm-column(1);
    .make-md-column(7);
    .make-lg-column(4);
  }
```

I found nothing about it :) and I wanted to ask the community

Comment: Wanted to ask us what?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Are you asking what type of CSS selector is best? i.e. `.col-md-6` vs `.left .col-md-6`

Comment: see @James Donnelly answer

Comment: Just wanted to mention, using the mixin will lead to a larger css file than the html approach.

Comment: i want to analyze pro  & cons about the 2 methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends, for simplicity you *could* of course use the "html approach", but if you stick to the "semantic web" and the idea behind HTML5 that is a very bad practice.

HTML should be used just for describing the content, the style should be entirely done by the CSS.

It's the base of html5 and, as I said, the semantic web.

Would you understand better this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-7 col-lg-4">I'm a div with a lot of content.</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7 col-lg-4">This is just a lorem ipsum dolor sine valor.</div>
</div>
```

...or this?

```
<article class="main-content">
  <div class="fact-box">I'm a div with a lot of content.</div>
  <div class="body-text">This is just a lorem ipsum dolor sine valor.</div>
</article>
```

It can be faster and maybe look more easy to build a site like in the first example if you memorize all the bootstrap classes, but then if for example you want to change a column to be a little bit larger you'll need to change not only the html of that column, but also all the related parts in your code.
On the other hand if you have a `_layout.sass` file you'll only need to edit a few lines that probably are very close to each other.

**TL;DR:** What i have presented here above is just an example, the main idea is: **Keep the *damn* content separated from the *fu**ing* style! ;-)**

This (content-style separation) is also the main reason why the `<b>`and similar html tags have been replaced with `<strong>` in html5, `b` stands for *"bold"*, which is style and `strong` stands for *"an important portion of text"*.

*Note: I used random bootstrap classes, just as an example.*

Comment: PS: For Content-Style separation also the "left" class is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Neither are really any better than the other in terms of performance and what they achieve.

However, the vast majority of Bootstrap developers are used to writing and maintaining code which uses the HTML approach. Very very few developers will even touch on Bootstrap's mixins and will find the mixin approach harder to work with.

Maintaining code written using the mixin approach would be difficult as you'd need to spend time learning the developer's code.

The HTML approach would most almost definitely be the best solution.

```
<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-7 col-lg-4">I'm on the left</div>
```

Comment: I totally disagree, how can you say this in 2015? :)

It can be a good idea only if you're creating a simple page in 15 minutes, you are too lazy to create a css and you just want to drop-in an framework not to make the page look like crap. :)

In all the other cases this should be archived via LESS/SASS!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to do with your html/css.

I personally use existing classes so that it's easier to understand and see what happens with that particular element on different screen sizes without having to check the css rules.

Use the mixins if you are going to reuse that class multiple times and it is particularly useful for your website.

Comment: yes, i use existing classes for this reason.. ctrl+u and i see the layout thought the classes

Comment: exactly, so unless you really require some functional thingy that is really specific but reused, using bootstrap columns is way more convenient